# Mysqli query performance multi-query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, facebook-php-sdk, mysqli-multi-query

I was just hoping someone could help me speed up 4 queries with a **multi query**.

**GOAL:** *`a single multi query to function as the single queries below.`*

Simple queries, i am checking one table to see if user is banned, then if not, i am getting row for the id and updating it's view count by 1.  If user is banned, i do not want the last to queries to complete.

***Thank you in advance for your help.***

current performance is around **1200ms.** (+1000ms avg for facebook graph api query).

***NOTE:*** af_freefeed.pageid & af_ban.pageid are both indexed in database.

**ALSO:** I have been studying and referencing from `http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php` i just can not see how to get this config into multi with the `if()`

```
$fconn = new mysqli($fdbhost, $fdbuser, $fdbpass, $fdbname) or die  ('Error connecting to mysqli');
// 12,000 rows for af_ban - bigint(255) : indexed
$q = sprintf('SELECT COUNT(pageid) AS numrowst FROM af_ban WHERE pageid = %s', $banpage);
$readtop = $fconn->query($q);
$rowtop = $readtop->fetch_assoc();

// 1.17 million rows for af_freefeed - bigint(255) : indexed
if($rowtop[numrowst] == 0){
$q = sprintf('SELECT COUNT(pageid) AS numrowsf FROM af_freefeed WHERE pageid = %s', $banpage);
$readf = $fconn->query($q);
$rowf = $readf->fetch_assoc();
// increment views
$read = $fconn->query("Update af_freefeed SET views = views + 1 WHERE pageid = ".$banpage."");
}
$q=$fconn->query("SELECT pagename,views,pageid FROM af_freefeed ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 0, 20");
unset($q);
unset($rowf);
unset($rowtop);
mysqli_close($fconn);
```

---

**actual request times.**

1. grah api: 1127.04610825ms.
2. conncect: 1.20711326599ms.
3. check banned: 0.405788421631ms.
4. get row: 418.189229965ms.
5. increment views: 472.24655151ms.
6. get top20: 94.31447983ms.

---

**Multi_query #1** *How to stop the multi query if user is banned?*

---

**Possible Contender:**  *943.8181ms. if added* : `933.1279ms. if banned`

1. 10ms difference if exit loop for banned. This leads me to believe the loop is completing all the queries before they are actually supposed to be executed, "next_result".  Or i have an error in how i looped the functions.
2. replaced `exit;` with `$thread_id = $fconn->thread_id; $fconn->kill($thread_id);`
   if banned 953.4719ms. **no gain**.

---

```
$banpage='234232874008';
$query  = "SELECT pagename,views,pageid FROM af_freefeed ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 0, 2;";
$query .= "SELECT pageid AS isbanned FROM af_ban WHERE pageid = \"".$banpage."\";";
$query .= "SELECT pageid AS isadded FROM af_freefeed WHERE pageid = \"".$banpage."\";";
$query .= "Update af_freefeed SET views = views + 1 WHERE pageid = \"".$banpage."\"";
/* execute multi query */
if ($fconn->multi_query($query)) {
   if ($result = $fconn->store_result()) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            print_r($row).'<br />';
      }
      $result->free();
   }
if ($fconn->more_results()) {
    while ($fconn->next_result()){ 
        if($thisresult = $fconn->store_result()){                   
            while (is_array($row = $thisresult->fetch_array())) {               
                if(isset($row['isbanned'])){
                    if($row['isbanned']===''.$banpage.''){
                $thread_id = $fconn->thread_id;
                $fconn->kill($thread_id);
                    // exit; 
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}           
}

unset($query);
unset($result);
unset($thisresult);
```

---

**Multi_query #2**  "current for benchmark" *How to remove duplicate fields in result set after next_result()?*

---

**2.667ms.** / **1032.2499ms.** but print_r is showing duplicate fields in $thisresults?

```
**Array
(
    [0] => 37
    [id] => 37
    [1] => 159616034235
    [pageid] => 159616034235
    [2] => 
    [userid] => 
    [3] => 30343
    [views] => 30343
    [4] => Walmart
    [pagename] => Walmart
)**
```

---

```
$query = "SELECT pageid AS isbanned FROM af_ban WHERE pageid = \"".$banpage."\";";
$query .= "SELECT pageid AS isadded FROM af_freefeed WHERE pageid = \"".$banpage."\";";
$query .= "SELECT * FROM af_freefeed ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 0, 20";
//$query .= "Update af_freefeed SET views = views + 1 WHERE pageid = \"".$banpage."\"";
/* execute multi query */
echo '<pre>';
$i=0;
if ($fconn->multi_query($query)) {
   if ($result = $fconn->store_result()) {
        //$row = $result->fetch_assoc();    
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print_r($row).'<br />';
      }
      $result->free();
    }
if ($fconn->more_results()) {
    while ($fconn->next_result()){ 
        if($thisresult = $fconn->store_result()){       
             while ($row2 = $thisresult->fetch_array()) {
                if(isset($row2['isadded'])){
                    if($row2['isadded']===''.$banpage.''){
                        $addone = $fconn->query("Update af_freefeed SET views = views + 1 WHERE pageid = ".$banpage."");

                    }
                }   
                                print_r($row2); 
            }

        }
    }
}       

}
/* determine our thread id */
$thread_id = $fconn->thread_id;
/* Kill connection */
$fconn->kill($thread_id);
//

echo '</pre><hr/>';
```

---

Comment: why not to measure these queries separately and find out which one slows down the whole bunch?

Comment: why do you think that a multi query will speed it up?

Comment: why don't you protect your queries from sql injections?

Comment: ty @YourCommonSense Facebook processes $banpage before i get it, it always returns object id, unless you see something in this one plugin i do not. 
all 620 lines of code look secure to me, but i am not smartest.

Comment: And did you try measuring each query separately as suggested?

Comment: Why do you think using mysql_multi_query() will speed it up? The first thing to do is to identify what is taking too long to execute, then optimize that part.

Comment: @jocelyn i do not know if i will gain meaningful performance from a multi query because the only one i was able to get working correctly i can not stop loop if user is banned.  All users so far have only assisted in ways i have already tried.  Can you get the multi to work as i expect?

Comment: people are voting me down, because i am asking to turn 4 single queries into a working stoppable multiquery?  

I need a moderator, and an oracle engineer.

Comment: Also using the multi is going to reduce the server turnaround.  Just the mutli i wrote gained 150ms in performance.  If i can get it to stop if user is banned and not run last 2 queries i will have found zen.

Comment: 150ms gain for the multi query @ 10 million requests last month would have saved me 111 hours of database run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT :** So now, the **conclusion:** (test case below)

You **cannot** control the execution of subsequent statements of a multi-statement query.
You can therefore **not** use `multi_query()` in the way you wanted to.

Execute them all, or execute none.

---

Regarding
**Multi_query #2** "current for benchmark" How to remove duplicate fields in result set after next_result()?

Use `fetch_assoc()` or `fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` (both practically the same) instead of `fetch_array()`.

---

**About multi_query():**

I recently worked on a program using the MySQL C API, which mysqli uses, too.
[About multiple-statement query support the documentation states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html):

> Executing a multiple-statement string can produce multiple result sets or row-count indicators. Processing these results involves a different approach than for the single-statement case: After handling the result from the first statement, **it is necessary to check whether more results exist and process them in turn if so**. To support multiple-result processing, the C API includes the mysql_more_results() and mysql_next_result() functions. These functions are used at the end of a loop that iterates as long as more results are available. **Failure to process the result this way may result in a dropped connection to the server.**

(emphasize added)

This leads to the conclusion, that **aborting a multiple-statement query is not an intended feature**.

Moreover, I didn't find *any* resource explaining *when* subsequent queries are actually executed.
Calling `next_result()` doesn't neccessarily mean that the query hasn't been executed already.

---

**EDIT : TEST CASE**

To prove what I previously assumed, I created a test case:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'common');
$query = 'SELECT NOW() as time;';
$query .= 'SELECT NOW() as time;';
$query .= 'SELECT NOW() as time;';
$query .= 'SELECT NOW() as time;';

if($db->multi_query($query)) {
    // Current time
    echo "'multi_query()' executed at:\n\t\t"
        .date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";

    // First result
    if($result = $db->store_result()) {
        $i = 1;

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo "'NOW()' of result $i:\n\t\t".$row['time']."\n";
        $result->free();
        // Wait 5 seconds
        sleep(5);

        // Subsequent results
        while($db->more_results() && $db->next_result()) {
            $result = $db->store_result();
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $i++;
            echo "'NOW()' of result $i:\n\t\t".$row['time']."\n";
            // Wait 5 seconds
            sleep(5);
            $result->free();
        }
    }
}
$db->close();
?>
```

This results in:

```
'multi_query()' executed at:
        2013-05-10 10:18:47
'NOW()' of result 1:
        2013-05-10 10:18:47
'NOW()' of result 2:
        2013-05-10 10:18:47
'NOW()' of result 3:
        2013-05-10 10:18:47
'NOW()' of result 4:
        2013-05-10 10:18:47
```

Given that, it is obvious that all four statements of the query were executed directly after the call to `multi_query()`.
If they were only executed after calling `next_result()` there would be a 5 second delay caused by `sleep(5)` calls I added between the loop iterations.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the downvote? We are all here to learn, so correct me.

Comment: @shawn-e-carter: I added a test case which proves that your intended use of `multi_query()` does not work.

Comment: wonderful, i wish i could have found this in the documents.  executes on query, and will return duplicate results.

Comment: sir, you are truly and scholar and a gentleman.  You have not only answered all my questions but you confirmed all of my guesses.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `index` in getting count. Like for example `COUNT(pageid)`. It will speed up your query.

**Update**

You can also try this **[link](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/three-easy-ways-to-optimize-your-mysql-queries/6137168)** for further explanation

Comment: why the minus 1? Please explain

Comment: where do you see minus 1 ?

Comment: thank you constatine, this shaved off about 400ms avg.  I am sure the multi query will perform alot better, i am just not good with mysqli yet.

Comment: thank you again for the update constatine, but i am using mysqli, the mysql driver is being depreciated. 
i have been reading for days.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: No problem. By the way I saw the minus 1 just before the plus 1's. Nevertheless, I'm glad it helped you out a little bit though.

Answer (score 1):

Please run following query in mysql and check your query run time :

```
CREATE INDEX pagidIndex ON af_ban (pageid(11));
CREATE INDEX pagidFeedIndex ON af_freefeed (pageid(11));
CREATE INDEX viewsIndex ON af_freefeed (views(11));
```

Comment: the index is already created. 

SQL query:

CREATE INDEX pagidIndex ON af_ban(

pageid( 11 )
)
MySQL said: 

#1089 - Incorrect sub part key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique sub keys

Comment: Sorry, I think there is problem in my SQL script.

Comment: to mention, the index has to be the full 255 characters for each value, i am not matching close, i am matching exact.  Any reason for this?

Comment: The size of field which you are making index, should match the size of the index in our case you can see 11 is the size of index, error is occure due to your field size in not 11. please match the size of the pageid and views field with the index. If it is resolving your problem please vote. Also mind that, field should not be a uniq key field or primary key field.

Comment: it is not addressing problem.

Comment: What is your problem, it is query performance, right, only indexing you can do. if you want more optimization you should give your complete db schema and data access process.

Comment: turning the 4 queries into a multi query where i would see a gain if the page is banned.

Comment: if the page is banned the queries should stop and exit.  it seems with the multi query so far, if a page is banned is not seeing any gain, leading me to believe that the queries are all running or something.  
in theory if i only run the first 2 queries i should see gain correct?

Comment: Can you write stored procedure. you can do it all in single call, using stored procedure.

Comment: this could work, what would happen if moved the banned to a new database, with multi i can switch connections on the fly, but the procedure would not work correct?  I am really hoping to figure out why there is not gain the multi query when user is banned, since the other 2 queries should not run

Comment: You can use stored procedure for multiple database if both are on same server. also you can use condition in stored procedure to manage the query which you want to run or not.

Answer (score 1):

> > i am checking one table to see if user is banned, then if not, i am getting row for the id and updating it's view count by 1.

The following query may help you to update the view count. I assume that you already know the page_id.

UPDATE af_freefeed SET views=views+1 WHERE page_id=%s and page_id not in (select page_id from af_ban WHERE page_id=%s);

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT af_freefeed.pageid FROM af_freefeed left join af_ban ".
               "on (af_freefeed.pageid = af_ban.pageid) ".
               "where af_freefeed.pageid = %s and ".
               "af_ban.pageid is null limit 1", $pageid);
```

to replace your first two queries.

The existence of a record in the results should indicate an unbanned user requesting the resource. Then you can do your update your views.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i used this with 2 single queries and in combo with another multi.  
No gain on total.  I think my goal of a single mutli is never going to fly, i cannot stop or kill the threads before they run "incase of banned pages".

Comment: this smells like it's something wrong with the way the indexes on pageid are defined on one or both of the tables. It might be worth droping and rebuilding the pageid index on each of the tables.

Comment: ty @Orangepill i have dropped and rebuilt over and over, the issue i am having is stopping the multi query if the user is banned, it seems the last 2 queries always run, or i am not killing them in the right spot, or you just cannot interupt and kill a multiquery thread in myslqi.  
It is looking like i will have to run 2 multi queries, the second only running if user is not in banned table. 
I am going to use your build, with a multi behind a condition and see if there is noticeable gain.

Comment: https://anotherfeed.com/widgets/mysqli.php?set=approved

*** 970.0301ms.  that is just your query

Comment: if you could, i am having a problems returning the page id as an array with your query.